# Leaflet clean checkbox in control layers

Tags: javascript, python, html, leaflet, gis

I want to remove a layer from the map and uncheck its control layer checkbox. According to the code bellow the layer is removed from the map, however its checkbox remain checked in control layers. Any hint on how I can clean or uncheck the layer checkbox after removing it from the map?

```
map.on('layeradd', function (event) {
    if (event.layer == layer1) {
        $('#layer1')[0].textContent = 'MyLayer'
        $('#legend-layer2')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: show')

        if (map.hasLayer(layer2)) {
            map.removeLayer(layer2)
        }
```

Comment: This should work as you intend - the layer control hooks add/remove events on its layers and checks/unchecks as required. Can you provide an example of the problem?

Comment: @peeebeee, Leaflet was not entirely happy with layer removal inside layer event. The fix was to set layer removal in setTimeout event processing function with slight delay: map.on('layeradd', function (event) {
  if (event.layer == layer1) {
    $('#layer1')[0].textContent = 'MyLayer'
    $('#legend-layer1')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: show')
    if (map.hasLayer(layer2)) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        map.removeLayer(layer2);
      }, 5);
    }
  }
});